# Mockito doThrow not throwing Exception

Tags: java, mockito

```
I want to execute the catch block of the below code.

public String getResult() {
    try {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

i write the test case as follows,

```
@Test
public void getResultTest() throws Exception{
    doThrow(Exception.class).when(mockInetAddress).getLocalHost();
    mockTestClassObj.getResult();
    //code for verify exception
}
```

This executes fine instead throws exception. Can't i throw exception in this scenario?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Answer (score 0):

getLocalHost() is a static method so you cannot mock it easily

Take a look to [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)